# How to set up matlab ODE function for cos(theta)

Tags: matlab, ode

I want to create an ODE file for the equation d^2theta/dt^2 - cos(theta) = 0
I have this:

```
function dYdt = osciODE(t,Y,~,theta)
dYdt = zeros(2,1);                      

dYdt (1) = Y(2);
dYdt (2) = -cos(theta1);
```

But I don't think this is right as dYdt (1) would be for d^2x/dt^2

Can I replace it with theta like this?

Comment: If you did your changes in the dependent variable consistently, then the answer would be rather clear. You use theta, Y, x all for the same dependent variable, even mixing these.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this ODE is :

```
[t,y] = ode23(@osciode,[0 20],[2; 0]);

plot(t,y(:,1),'-o',t,y(:,2),'-o')
title('Solution osciode with ODE23 : y1=y ; y2=dy/dt');
grid on
xlabel('t');ylabel('y');
legend('y_1','y_2')

%%

function dydt = osciode(t,y)

dydt = [y(2); cos(y(1))];

end
```

[image]

`y` is `theta`